# Deploy WPF Application with squirrel.windows and no windows 10 entry in Program & Features

Tags: installation, nuget-package, squirrel.windows

The goal is to deploy with squirrel.windows, to can install, update, uninstall and to see it in Program & Features in Windows 10. To have add the end also a MyApp.msi file would be a plus.

**Case 1:**
I created a NugetPackage with the Nuget Package Explorer. Than releasify it over the Package Manager Console "squirrel --releasify myNuget.1.0.0.nupkg", get the release files, click setup.exe to install and the icon of the app appears in the windows menu.

In the Windows Program & Features it doesn't appear in the list of installed Applications.

The update is working when I deploy a next nugetPackage of my app. It creates a myApp.msi file which is nice.

**Case 2:**
When I use the Squirrel App on GitHub "https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows" it shows it. - Super.

The update is not working when I deploy a next nugetPackage of my app. It creates ***not*** a myApp.msi file.

With the small testApp it is working with absolutely the same code, but also no myApp.msi file. The difference is that it uses DevExpress Dll's and it has 54 Dll's in the production app. There are 13 Dll's in myTestApp.

**Install & Update Code**

```
public static async Task CheckForUpdates()
{
    using (var mgr = new UpdateManager(DEPLOYMENT_PATH))
    {
        // Note, in most of these scenarios, the app exits after this method
        // completes!
        SquirrelAwareApp.HandleEvents(
            onInitialInstall: v => mgr.CreateShortcutForThisExe(),
            onAppUpdate: v => mgr.CreateShortcutForThisExe(),
            onAppUninstall: v => mgr.RemoveShortcutForThisExe(),
            onFirstRun: () => ShowTheWelcomeWizard = true);
    }
}

public static bool ShowTheWelcomeWizard { get; set; }
```

Please help me to reach my goal.

Greetings Fredy

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure **Title** is not empty while packaging the Application.
https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/issues/1544

[image]

I found here: